# Paragraph inside object tag

Tags: html, css

I am embedding SVG image inside `<object>` tag:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/quatrefoil.svg" width="100%"
  height="100%" class="svg-content"></object>
```

I tried putting a paragraph `<p class="arvo">` within the `<object>` tag, but the text does not show up. How should I write so that paragraph text is viewed ontop of the SVG object?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or something so we can view your problem?

Comment: Things within an `<object>` tag will not be rendered, unless the data in the `<object>` tag itself can’t be rendered.

Comment: ok... Its my first time here.. In the fiddles.. is there any place to link to images.. If i can't upload my .svg image you really can't see anything..Anyhow... here is the link to fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/jingliang3/asmxkgp4/

Answer (score 1):

Use a shared parent

```
<div class="container">
    <svg ...>
    <p class="description">...</p>
</div>
```

along with

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: {x}px;
    height: {x}px;
}

.container svg {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container .description {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999; /* or something sufficiently large */
}
```